# How can I use Hibernate 6 with Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, hibernate-6.x

I need to use Hibernate version 6.0.0.Alpha7, since they have solved the following issue:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050

Hibernate dependency is declared using quarkus extension:

```
<quarkus.platform.version>2.1.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
(...)
<dependency>
       <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
       <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I think this is still using Hibernate 5.5.6.Final. How can I use Hibernate 6.0.0.Alpha7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Hibernate 6 with Quarkus.
We will bump to that version sometime in the future, but for now we are on 5.x.

If that issue is very important to you, I propose you ask the Hibernate team to backport the fix to the 5.x line

**Update**

Quarkus will switch to Hibernate 6 in Quarkus 3.0 (the switch had already been made in the main branch)

Comment: When can we use Hib 6 with Panache?

Comment: It will be available in Quarkus 3 which will be released very soon